# Code after $.post() is executed before post-request is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, console

I am trying to get data from a server using a post request (jQuery's $.post) and assign it to a JavaScript variable.

The code is as follows:

```
function getData() {        
    var zones = DUMMY_zones;
    var workers = [];

    console.log("1");

    $.post('server/main.php', {info: 'req_workers'}, function(result) {
        var result = JSON.parse(result);

        console.log("2");

    });


    console.log("3");
    return [zones, workers];
}
```

Yet strangely, the return is executed before the $.post request finsihes, so that `workers` is undefined variable. The console output is as follows:

```
ppe_c_js.js:82 1
ppe_c_js.js:90 3
ppe_c_js.js:85 2
```

How can I execute the code sequentially?

Thank you!

Comment: That’s what async code does. It sends off the request and continues with the rest of the code. At some point in the future, after the post returns, the callback is called and 2 is printed.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the jquery post `synchronous`. but this is a bad practice. so, your browser will be in freezing state during the operation.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType,
  async:false
});
```

Comment: I see! But since it's bad practice, how can I ensure that the `workers` variable is set before I use? Otherwise I'll have the issue of the variable being empty.

Comment: in synchronous operations, the code is running sequentially. so, workers variable value will be available everywhere after define and set.

Comment: You can put it next to console 2. If you have a more complex setup you can use promises https://api.jquery.com/promise/